# Why is the react router redirecting all requests on nginx server?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a react app deployed under `/` at a nginx server. I have an old Django app deployed under `/old`.

If I open a new browser window and access `/old` directly, I can access the Django app without a problem. If I first open the react app, all following requests to `/old` redirect to the react app. This is only cleared by closing the browser window (tab is not enough).

React router:

```
function render(location) {
  Router.resolve(routes, location)
    .then(renderComponent)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Nginx config:

```
location /old {
    proxy_redirect off;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi.sock;
    uwsgi_intercept_errors on;
}

location / {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Disclaimer: I am not the developer of the react app and know little about it. I am pretty sure that my nginx config is correct. Instead, I think this is due to some redirect caching/browser foo react is doing, but I have no idea how to stop it.

Any help?

Comment: What I noticed: commenting out the call to `registerServiceWorker();` and everything works fine. Unfortunately, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The React app has a client-side router that is intercepting page clicks and not issuing HTTP `GET` requests to the server, but rather the browser router.

This would explain why, with a clean browser session, you're able to access to the expected `/old` Django app, since the initial `GET` request must always get routed to the server.

In these cases, the React app hasn't been loaded, and therefore the client-side router can't been engaged. However, when you access the `/` route, and React is loaded, the client-side router will kick it, and intercept all subsequent requests.

You could theoretically hack around this by whitelisting some routes like `/old`, and instead of passing these to the router, the browser just does something like `window.location = https://yoursite.com/old`.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you. We're thinking about taking this approach.